# Eclipse: import folder of source code to other projects

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have project A: in project I hava a package A. (In project folder, it's just a folder A with many *.java).

I create a project B: how I import folder A to project B to use modules I have created. (If I create package A from project A: I must compile each file to *.class, and I cannot modified source code again, and that not what I want).

This work frustrate me so much. Because I often do step by step (in Project B): create a new package A-->create class a'-->copy code of class a' of projectA to this class @@)

---

**Edit**

Oh. thanks for help of Perception. Very nice and very detail to me. thanks for Baldrick help me over come this trick,too. (first time, I work like Perception say, but I don't see project A. and don't see nothing :-O. And I try Baldrick promise: "This way the classes in project A are available to other project." ).

But, I think this solution has some strict:

1)  projectA must be open. If not, projectB will notice error.

2)  This work mean projectA and projectB are working together. But, I just like projectB inherits some useful class from projectA. (and I can change some code, and this work will not change project A).

Easy example: projectA has class Car. projectB has class Truck. class Car has some useful sub-class like Run(). Petrol().  projectB will use Run() class and change something in Petrol().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to include a variety of targets in a projects classpath, including other projects. To modify your `Project B's` classpath, right click on it and select `Properties`, then `Java Build Path->Projects`. Click add and select your `Project A`. When done, click ok to exit and Eclipse will do a rebuild.

This is how you include one project in another project's classpath - please, please ***dont*** copy the classes the way you are doing now, this leads to a maintenance nightmare. See screenshot below for a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two steps:

- Right click of project A, choose "Properties", go to "Java build path". On the tab "Order and export", be sure that your source folders are checked. This way the classes in project A are available to other project.
- Right click of project B, choose "Properties", go to "Java build path". On the tab "Project", add your project A. This way project B will now use classes from project A.