# Java import a package form on other project

Tags: java

I Have some function "foo()" on ~/workspace/pjr01/onepkg/f.java and I want to use it on my other project which is located on ~/workspace/pjr02/twopkg/some.java
How do I access f.foo() from some.java

```
~/workspace/pjr01/onepkg/f.java
~/workspace/pjr02/twopkg/some.java
```

Comment: Can't you just copy it in to your other project? You're not meant to access a method across projects, unless it's part of a library.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: yes I thought of that that is the easiest way but if you are working on a huge project you may need some you rather not do that

Comment: yes I'm using eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: import folder of source code to other projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163501/eclipse-import-folder-of-source-code-to-other-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, you can right click the project `pjr01` -> select properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Click on Add -> Add the project `pjr02`.

Once you have finished development, you have to build a jar of `pjr02` then add it to the classpath of `proj01` before releasing project.

[image]

Comment: That's ridiculous. Why add a library of the other project just to use one method from it? Surely the OP can just copy that method.

Comment: @Troubleshoot The OP gave an example of calling one method but in one of his [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275412/java-import-a-pakage-form-on-other-project/19275757#comment28538710_19275412) he is talking about a huge project...

Comment: Thank mate! it will be usefull